# Display application icon on click of share button + Meteor

Tags: cordova, mobile, meteor

I'm on wiki page and selecting some text, then click on Share button of mobile.
There will be lots of icon like "Gmail", "Facebook", "Whatsapp" and many more, my application icon should be there to share on my web app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908224/share-something-to-a-phonegap-app. This might help

Comment: Yes, That true, but what about ios build?And We have to edit that file manually. Is there any way to do it dynamically by code? So every time we do not need to modify that file?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436544/share-image-using-share-extension-in-ios8

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! but The above link for Objective C, I'm using Meteor + cordova. And I want to do that through cordova for both.

Comment: What about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105698/cordova-sharing-browser-url-to-my-ios-app-clipper-ios-share-extension

Answer (score 0):

A google search brought me to this. It seems in android you can use a cordova plugin like this one https://github.com/stample/cordova-sharingreceptor.

To add this plugin to your meteor app add the following JavaScript to its package.js:

```
Cordova.depends({
    'com.phonegap.plugins.sharingreceptor': 'https://github.com/stample/cordova-sharingreceptor'
});
```

From https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-integration#meteor-packages-with-cordova-dependencies

For ios I found this [Cordova: sharing browser URL to my iOS app (Clipper ios share extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105698/cordova-sharing-browser-url-to-my-ios-app-clipper-ios-share-extension)

Creating your own extension and then copying the extension contents to `cordova/platforms/ios/` will work according to the above stack post